# Communication between more than two python scripts using stdin and stdout

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have found a lot of posts explaining how to make two python scripts communicate, most of the time by using `subprocess` package. I need to make the same, but **with `n` scripts**.

Simplifying my case, I have three python scripts (master, slave_1, slave_2) that should communicate with `stdin` and `stdout`. The communication should be handled by a fourth script (orchestrator).

What I am trying to achieve :

[image]

```
# master.py
print('M')
for _ in range(6):
    value = input() + 'M'
print(value)

# slave_1.py
print(input() + '1')

# slave_2.py
print(input() + '2')
```

Following the diagram above, I would like my `orchestrator.py` to output 'M1M2M1M2M1M2' when I run it.

For the moment, I tried with `subprocess`, but I ran into a lot of issues, such as being stuck on `stdout.readline()`. Here is a very simple example of my `orchestrator.py`.

```
import subprocess

master = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'master.py'],
                      stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

slave_1 = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'slave_1.py'],
                      stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

slave_2 = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'slave_2.py'],
                      stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for _ in range(3):
    slave_1.stdin.write(master.stdout.readline())
    master.stdin.write(slave_1.stdout.readline())

    slave_2.stdin.write(master.stdout.readline())
    master.stdin.write(slave_2.stdout.readline())
```

Any thought about this ?

I should precise I cannot change the code of neither master nor slaves.

Comment: this is probably not a good way to architect this, I would rethink the problem honestly

Comment: Yes I agree, this is the purpose of my question. Now that I have tried with subprocess (and now that it does not work) any advice on how to rethink the problem is very welcome. The only constraint is that it has to use stdin and stdout

Comment: it would help if your question included actual context as opposed to a trivial example, then people can offer more robust alternatives

Comment: But in SO "Before posting" section it is recommended to give a minimal example instead of the entire context... in addition, I should precise I cannot change anything on master and slaves, so I cannot redesign anything, I can only change orchestrator code.

Comment: For the level of parallelism that you want to achieve I would look at the `threading` library - will get rid of the blocking problems that you will always experience with the sort of architecture you are proposing. The downside is you now have threading to deal with.

Comment: @wwii That's it, they only communicate via stdin and stdout and I cannot write any adapter.

Comment: @dwagon that seems to be a good solution, will try it !

Comment: You can also use message queues via rabbitmq using pika https://pika.readthedocs.io/ to tackle this problem

Comment: So… Master should read lines of input alternately from Orchestrator and from Slave 1, which (along with Slave 2) is invoked repeatedly as needed to feed it?  Do you know in advance how much input/output each process needs/produces?

Comment: @Loheek You might want to take a look at the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module. For the slaves you can use a `Pool` and maybe a separate `Process` for the master, though it's not completely clear how this communication should flow.